# Why won't the image center no matter how many different align functions I use?

Tags: html, css

I have this icon that I want to be above my text. In this section of the website, it says, "LUNCH". In my div, if I put the image after the text, then it perfectly aligns center. However, if I put it before the text like I want it, it won't be centered anymore. I have also tried putting it in a separate div, container, and classes. Its also weird since my text is already aligning center when I haven't told it to in CSS, but it is what I want.

This allows it to center:
[Here is an example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqo1j.png)

```
<div class="titlecontainer">
  <h1  class="title">LUNCH</h1>
  <img src ="lunch.png" class= 'center'/> <!-- This allows it to center-->
</div>
```

This does not allow it to center:
[Here is an example image][2]

```
<div class="titlecontainer">
  <img src ="lunch.png" class= 'center'/> <!-- This doesn't allow it to center-->
  <h1  class="title">LUNCH</h1>
</div>
```

You can see this when you run it as a part of the full code: (I deleted the rest of the code since it was distracting)

```
/*title*/

.titlecontainer {
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0;
}

img.center {
  display: block;
  width: 400px;
}

img.center,
.title {
  align-items: center;
}

.title {
  font-family: 'Catamaran', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 350;
  font-size: 350%;
  padding-top: 5%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Catamaran:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=PT+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Arsenal&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="headerA">
  <header>
    <div class="container">
      <img src="logoDE.png" alt="logo" class="logo">
      <div id="myde">

        <a class="a" href="https://d-e.myschoolapp.com/app#login">
          <div class="myyDEcontainer">
            <img src="myyDE.png" alt="myDE" class="myDE"></a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="deorg">
        <a class="de" href="https://www.d-e.org" class="de">d-e.org</a>
      </div>
  </header>
  </div>

  <div class="headerB">
    <header>
      <div class="containerB">
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a class="a" href="ls6.html">LS + 6th Grade</a></li>
            <li><a class="a" href="upms.html">MS & US</a></li>
            <li><a class="a" href="staff.html">Staff Members</a></li>
            <div class="dropdown">
              <div class="hamburger container">
                <div class="dropbtn">
                  <div="dropbtnicon">
                    <div class="iconline"></div>
                    <div class="iconline"></div>
                    <div class="iconline"></div>
                </div>
                <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
              <a class="c" href="homepage.html">Covid Home Page</a>
              <a class="c" href="transportation.html">Transportation</a>
              <a class="c" href="maskguidelines.html">Mask Guidelines</a>
              <a class="c" href="lunch.html">Lunch</a>
              <a class="c" href="maps.html">Maps</a>
              <a class="c" href="emails.html">Dr. D's Emails</a>
              <a class="c" href="covideducation.html">COVID-19 Education</a>
            </div>
      </div>
      </ul>
      </nav>
  </div>
  </header>
  <center>

    <div class="titlecontainer">
      <img src="lunch.png" class='center' />
      <h1 class="title">LUNCH</h1>
    </div>
```

Please advise me on what to do.

This is what happened when I tried Yogesh Singh’s answer: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jtmgk.jpg)

[2]: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0ztl.png![enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0ztl.png!%5Benter) image description here]

Comment: Hi, perhaps use a flexbox or table-cell?

Comment: Things that are suspect: Title container has a width of 70%. The title container appears to be wrapped in a `<center>` tag. The `img.center` has a width of 400px. I think those are what is screwing things up.

Comment: Can you please remove code until just enough code remains so that the problem is demonstracted, a [mre]? All of the extra code around the header, nav, etc. is just distracting and doesn't appear to have anything to do with the problem.

Comment: Why do people always just downvote questions? It literally says that this person has tried so many things. And someone even deleted some of their explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Well, the code is working for me, but the HTML syntax has a lot of errors.

The hrefs need to have %26 instead of &

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Catamaran:wght@300%26display=swap' type='text/css'>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=PT+Sans%26display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Arsenal%26display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```
<div id="headerA">
            <header>
                <div class="container">
                    <img src="logoDE.png" alt="logo" class="logo">
                    <div id="myde">
                        <a class="a" href="https://d-e.myschoolapp.com/app#login">
                            <div class="myyDEcontainer">
                                <img src="myyDE.png" alt="myDE" class="myDE">
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="deorg">
                        <a class="de" href="https://www.d-e.org">d-e.org</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </header>
        <div class="headerB">
            <header>
                <div class="containerB">
                    <nav>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a class="a" href="ls6.html">LS + 6th Grade</a></li>
                            <li><a class="a" href="upms.html">MS & US</a></li>
                            <li><a class="a" href="staff.html">Staff Members</a></li>
                            <div class="dropdown">
                                <div class="hamburger container">
                                    <div class="dropbtn">
                                        <div="dropbtnicon">
                                            <div class="iconline"></div>
                                            <div class="iconline"></div>
                                            <div class="iconline"></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="dropdown-content">
                                    <a class="c" href="homepage.html">Covid Home Page</a>
                                    <a class="c" href="transportation.html">Transportation</a>
                                    <a class="c" href="maskguidelines.html">Mask Guidelines</a>
                                    <a class="c" href="lunch.html">Lunch</a>
                                    <a class="c" href="maps.html">Maps</a>
                                    <a class="c" href="emails.html">Dr. D's Emails</a>
                                    <a class="c" href="covideducation.html">COVID-19 Education</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </header>
            <center>
                <div class="titlecontainer">
                    <img src="lunch.png" class='center' />
                    <h1 class="title">LUNCH</h1>
                </div>
            </center>
```

This code does seam to work.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you said that text gets centered even though you haven't added any such css which is wrong. You've following CSS for the text "LAUNCH":-

```
img.center,
.title {
  align-items: center;
}
```

Now, making the image center, you've to change the CSS of div wrapping the img tag as follows:

```
.titlecontainer {
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0;
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Or

You can use `display: flex`

Or

Giving `text-align: center` property to the wrapper div will work because `text-align` property works on block containers and div is a block container. Hence, `text-align: center` to wrapper div will make the image and text center aligned.

Comment: So I tried this, and it only worked on one page. Now it appears as the picture I have added in my post (the pic with email icon)

Comment: Okay. I think instead of creating a center class for the image, try applying the `display: flex; justify-content: center` properties to the wrapping divs. That way you've to apply a center class to those divs in which you want the images to be center-aligned.

Answer (score 0):

there's also an easy way to do this, just replace text-align:

Comment: oops the full thing didn't pop up replace text-align: center; with float:center;

Comment: I have already tried this unfortunately. But, thank you for responding!